# Executereader and execute non-query in a single connection in ado.net

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ado.net, connection-string, sqldatareader

The below snippet employs multiple queries inside the same connection string. first i'm selecting the some datas from the DB then before closing the datareader(dr) i would like to do some validations so if satisfies i ll insert those value into the table in the DB within the while loop of dr. There i get the error as there's already an open datareader so i cannot use another query before closing it. so i ve temporarily used another connection string pointing to the same database and i do the insert qry using that connection object(conn1). but wat is the other way to do this without using another connection string.
Any help ll be greatly appreciated. Thx.

```
public XmlDocument LBS_Offer_Scheduler(string dev_token, float lat, float llong)
    {
        XmlDocument xml_doc = null;
        bool result = false;
        int row_affect = 0;
        int x = (int)Math.Truncate(lat);
        int y = (int)Math.Truncate(llong);

        string qry = "select Store_id,Store_Latitude,Store_Longitude from tbl_FB_Store_Details where Store_Latitude like '"
            + x + "%' and Store_Longitude like '" + y + "%'";
        conn.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, conn);
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            Store_Id = dr[0].ToString();
            str_dlat = dr[1].ToString();
            str_dlon = dr[2].ToString();
            double dlat = Convert.ToDouble(str_dlat);
            double dlon = Convert.ToDouble(str_dlon);
            dist_in_sqmts = obj_distance.distance(lat, llong, dlat, dlon);
            id = Convert.ToInt32(Store_Id);
            if (dist_in_sqmts < 200.00)
            {
                string insert_qry = "insert into tbl_FB_Offer_PushNote values('" + dev_token + "', "+ id + ",'" + DateTime.Now + "','N')";
                conn1.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand(insert_qry, conn1);
                row_affect = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn1.Close();
            }
        }
        conn.Close();
        if (row_affect > 0)
            result = true;
        xml_doc = x_doc.result(result);
        return xml_doc;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set MultipleActiveResultSets=True in the connection string. 
See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h32h3abf%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: thx Steven. The MultipleActiveResultSets made my work a lot easier. but does it slow down the process? i guess!

Comment: MARS cannot be used when using "context connection=true" in CLR-procedures: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2575accc-72ac-4fab-99c1-1683afa39d72/context-connection-and-multipleactiveresultsets-can-have-both-at-the-same-time?forum=sqlnetfx

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `DataSet` class - `SqlDataAdapter` and `DataTable` to retrieve result from the database.

```
string qry = "select Store_id,Store_Latitude,Store_Longitude
      from tbl_FB_Store_Details where Store_Latitude 
            like @x and Store_Longitude like @y";
SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand(qry,conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@x", x + "%");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@y", y + "%");

SqlDataAdapter adp=new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
adp.Fill(dt);

foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
 {
     Store_Id = dr[0].ToString();
     str_dlat = dr[1].ToString();
     str_dlon = dr[2].ToString();
     double dlat = Convert.ToDouble(str_dlat);
     double dlon = Convert.ToDouble(str_dlon);
     dist_in_sqmts = obj_distance.distance(lat, llong, dlat, dlon);
     id = Convert.ToInt32(Store_Id);
     if (dist_in_sqmts < 200.00)
      {
           .....
       }
 }
```

Comment: good insight. cant this be done in datareader? cos using datatable and dataset makes the coding less convincing na